# React TransitionGroup componentWillLeave no action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I  have strange problem with TransitionGroup in React. First time somehow I managed to create group and component that stucks and doesn't update based on state values.

Have one component(A) that always has TransitionGroup. When state changes it rerenders itself. In TransitionGroup I add/remove other Components(B) (yes they have unique keys). in component B i have function componentWillLeave which just calls to callback as I don't want to perform any animations on leave. And these  damn B components stays in my component A! But if i do setTimeout() in componentWillLeave function for 10ms it detaches properly. May anyone has idea why this happens or had same issue?

Thanks,

T

Comment: please post some relevant code, in order for us to help you debug. also you can set `transitionLeave={ false }` on your transition components if you do not want them to have a leave animation

Answer (score 1):

It is well known problem with TransitionGroup and CSSTransitionGroup, more discussion is here - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1326#issuecomment-135577995. will be fixed in 0.14 release.